# flask_sqlalchemy error when trying to load database schema: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a python web application that will connect to an existing sqlite database. Here is my code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///history.db"
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
app.app_context().push()
db.reflect()

History = db.Table(
         "history", 
         db.Model.metadata,
         autoload=True,
         autoload_with=db.engine
    )

print(db.Table("history", db.Model.metadata).columns.items())
```

But this code generates the following error:

```
TypeError: Additional arguments should be named <dialectname>_<argument>, got 'autoload'
```

I can find documentation for loading an existing database schema with `sqlalchemy`, but nothing for loading a database schema using `flask_sqlalchemy`

How do I load my sqlite database into a flask application using `flask_sqlalchemy`?

## Update 1

Thanks to the reply from `M69k65y`, I was finally able to solve this!

Updated code:

```
History = db.Table(
         "history", 
         db.Model.metadata
         autoload_with=db.engine
    )
```

and this gave me an error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchTableError: history
```

I modified my connection URL to use an absolute path:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///C:\\Projects\\HistoryDatabase\\history.db"
```

And I was finally able to get the table schema!

NOTE: I am using Python 3.8.10 on Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to include the argument `autoload`.
As of [SQLAlchemy 2.0](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/changelog/migration_20.html#implicit-and-connectionless-execution-bound-metadata-removed), the `autoload_with` argument should be used instead of `autoload`. (See the

Your code would look like this:

```py
History = db.Table(
     "history", 
     db.Model.metadata,
     autoload_with=db.engine
)
```

Comment: Thanks! This put me on the road to solving my problem! I have added an update to the question with my process.